# Logstash config not mapping properly to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, logstash, config

I am currently pushing data from Oracle to ES using logstash. In logstash conf, i am putting my host as https://es.prod.xxxx.xxxx.com:443, but on running the job, it fails stating the following- 
Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"https://xxxx:xxxxxx@es.prod.xxxx.xxxx.com:9200/

PS : not sure why it maps to 9200, when i explicitly say 443, can anyone shed some light to where 9200 could be hard-coded or I might be missing something?

I have tried curl commands to see connectivity, works fine from vm. tried different port and combinations

```
              hosts => [ "https://es.prod.xxxx.com:443" ]
              user => "xxxxxxxxx"
              password => "xxxxxxxxxxx"
              doc_as_upsert => true
              cacert => '/app/home/xxxx/xxxx.crt'
              manage_template => false
              index => "index-1"
            }
```

Connecting to or error on port 433 instead of 9200

Comment: 9200 is the default port for HTTP traffic to Elasticsearch, that's why it could be trying to connect there. However, explicitly setting the port in the host URL should replace the default setting...   
Is it possible there is a proxy involved in the network communications that you need to setup in the logstash output?